# ReactJS children component lost its state when rendered with a different function

Tags: reactjs, state, children

When writing a ReactJS component, I found the child component loses its state once a while. Turns out it happens if the child component is rendered with a different render function.

i.e.

Parent component has 2 sub-render functions and, due to different conditions, 
it either renders the child component in the body, or in the header.

```
    ...

    renderInHeader = () => (<Header><ChildComponent /></Header>);

    renderInBody = () => (<Body><ChildComponent /><Body>);

    render = () => {
      if (somethingHappens) {
        return this.renderInHeader();
      }
      return this.renderInBody();
    }

    ...
```

That means, when `somethingHappens`, it will use a different render function to render the `ChildComponent`.

Then, `ChildComponent` would lose its state. (Child component's state get reset).

---

I understand why it happens, I'm actually slightly surprised that the child's state doesn't get reset more often (i.e. reset every time parent re-render that node).

However, what's the ideal solution to deal with it?

- Avoid using state in child component? (because it's not guaranteed safe?)
- Give a `key=` to the ChildComponent, so it can be treated as an independent node during re-render? (not sure if `key` works outside of mapper)
- Use `ref`? (no idea if it works that way)
- Use new "Portal" from react 16? (haven't tried yet)

---

Note: I know I can use variable for `Header` and `Body`, so there's only one render function needed. However, a real world case could be more complicated, there may be multiple child components distributed in different areas.

i.e.

```
        ...

    renderInBody = () => (
        <Body>
            <Header>
                <ChildComponent1 />
                <ChildComponent2 />
            </Header>
            <ChildComponent3 />
        </Body>
    );

    renderInHeader = () => (
        <Header>
            <ChildComponent3 />
            <ChildComponent1 />
            <Body>
                <ChildComponent2 />
            </Body>
        </Header>
    );

    render = () => {
      if (somethingHappens) {
        return this.renderInHeader();
      }
      return this.renderInBody();
    }

    ...
```

Here, Child Component 1,2,3 doesn't really change, just their position and parent's structure gets changed.

And, I don't feel it's a good solution to put the Child Component positioning strategy in `Header` and `Body` components.

Is it possible to keep ChildComponent's state?

Comment: Do u want to maintain the state od the child component?

Answer (score 1):

You can define variables for your child components and use them to order the rendering in the parent component. So your example code would become

```
renderInBody = (child1,child2,child3) => (
    <Body>
        <Header>
            {child1}
            {child2}
        </Header>
        {child3}
    </Body>
);

renderInHeader = (child1,child2,child3) => (
    <Header>
        {child3}
        {child1}
        <Body>
            {child2}
        </Body>
    </Header>
);

render = () => {
    let child1=<ChildComponent key={1}/>;
    let child2=<ChildComponent key={2}/>;
    let child3=<ChildComponent key={3}/>;
      if (somethingHappens) {
        return this.renderInHeader(child1,child2,child3);
      }
      return this.renderInBody(child1,child2,child2);
}
```

Make sure that your child components have unique keys so that they can maintain state.

Comment: Thanks, likely the best answer yet, though I haven't found any documentation saying `key` works outside of loops, gonna check the source and take a look later.

Answer (score 0):

`ChildComponent` should not be a part of `if-else` block since it is always rendered .

```
render = () => {
  const ParentComponent = somethingHappens ? Header : Body;
  return (
    <ParentComponent>
      <ChildComponent />
    </ParentComponent>
  );
};
```

Comment: I thought about it. and talked about it in the last "note" section. The thing is, there can be multiple Child Components, distributed randomly in multiple possible Parent Components. This solution doesn't work so well on that.

Comment: If you provide a real case ( with a real state of ChildComponent so on.. ) , we will give you pretty solution .

Answer (score 0):

Its better,if you create new instance of the `ChildComponent` every-time.

```
let alwaysNewChildComp  = <ChildComponent />

renderInHeader = () => (<Header>{alwaysNewChildComp}</Header>);

renderInBody = () => (<Body>{alwaysNewChildComp}<Body>);
```

OR

```
let alwaysNewChildComp = React.createClass({

      render: function () {
        return (<div><ChildComponent /></div>)
      }
})

renderInHeader = () => (<Header>{alwaysNewChildComp}</Header>);

renderInBody = () => (<Body>{alwaysNewChildComp}<Body>);
```

It will reset your `ChildComponent` state.

You can go further with [`redux`](https://redux.js.org/) also.

Comment: I used redux a lot, in fact maybe too much (as redux was originally designed for). Trying to scale back a little on some smaller projects, and create dumber components as more re-usable components. That's why I'm running into these reliability problem with states.